# Registering object field values Java

Tags: java, class, object, constructor, field

I've recently started programming with Java and I like to know if there is a way to register(like put in array or something) certain object field values.

In this case, for example all "name" values(private final String name) of created objects.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
public class Item {
    private int amount;
    private double price;
    private final String name;
    private final String type;
    private final String madeIn;

    Item(int amount, double price, String name, String type, String madeIn){
        this.amount=amount;
        this.madeIn=madeIn;
        this.name=name;
        this.type=type;
        this.price=price;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing stopping you from adding some static `Set` member to your class that would contain all the `name`s of the created instances.

Inside the `Item` constructor you can add `name` to this `Set`.

```
public class Item {
    private int amount;
    private double price;
    private final String name;
    private final String type;
    private final String madeIn;
    private static Set<String> registeredNames = new HashSet<String>();
    Item(int amount, double price, String name, String type, String madeIn)
    {
        registeredNames.add (name); // you should consider what you want to do
                                    // if the same name is passed to two instances
                                    // perhaps throw an exception  
        this.amount=amount;
        this.madeIn=madeIn;
        this.name=name;
        this.type=type;
        this.price=price;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you add some example?

Comment: @DevGambit Sure, see edit. You'll also need some static method to access the `registeredNames` Set, unless you only intend to use it internally.

Answer (score 4):

You have many data structures in Java in the `Collection` family like `List` or `Set`. You also have *associative* (key/value) collections with `Map` and its sub-classes.

Trying to read between the lines in your question, you may want to have some *collection* of `Item`s that you want to access through there `name` field.

Assuming the `name` is unique in an `Item` and you have *getters* for the properties:

```
Map<String, Item> itemsByName = new HashMap<>();

// put some items...
itemsByName.put(item1.getName(), item1);
itemsByName.put(item2.getName(), item2);
// etc...

// Looking for an item knowing its name
String key = "Foo";
Item itemFound = itemsByName.get(key);
if (itemFound==null) {
   System.out.println("There is no item whose name is " + key);
}
else {
   // do something with itemFound
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create a static `List` of names and keep on adding that in the constructor like:

```
private final static List<String> names = new LinkedList<String>();

public Item(..) {
    names.add(name);
}
```